# SQL Server : convert Varchar to XML - then operate on it and select data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, casting

I got a `Varchar` column which holds XML. I would like to convert them to JSON so I did a quick test.

Here is what worked so far:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @XML = '<content>
  <value>123456</value>
</content>'

SELECT
    '{"foo":"' + b.value('(./value)[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')  + '"}' 
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/content') AS a(b)
```

Result:

```
 {"foo":"123456"}
```

So far so good, but this does not do half the job that has to be done.

- I have lots of rows, and I want to convert all rows at once.
- I have multiple values inside a content tag and therefore I cannot just add a json prefix and suffix since inside that array there will be more than one ID.

I read this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15 but since my target column is a `VARCHAR` and has to be cast, it actually didn't help me...

So first I cast the values to xml:

```
SELECT CAST(mytextField.TEXTVALUE AS XML) AS xmlData
FROM myDataTable  
WHERE mytextFieldId = 12345
```

This returns the values as XML:

```
<content><value>12345</value></content>
<content><value>9874</value></content>
<content><value>Foo</value><value>Bar</value></content>
```

Now I'm stuck.

- How can I select this result in a new query?
- What would be the best approach to convert this to json format?

In the first snippet I added a prefix and a suffix to the value of the xmls value tag. How could I do this with the cast rows I selected?

Comment: The very *best* way is undoubtedly to upgrade to SQL Server 2017 so you get native JSON support, but I take it that's not an option. Doing this in SQL Server 2008 will require some involved quite involved string manipulation. Do you at least know for certain the markup is always of this form (i.e. a list of `<value>` nodes)? Solving this problem for dynamic markup is really quite undoable.

Comment: Upgrading to a supported version of sql server would be a first step. 2008 has been unsupported now for a few months. But if upgrading isn't an option I would strongly consider doing this with CLR. It is painless to convert xml to JSON and back with dotnet.